# Search Wireless adapter on MC75 device using OpenNETCF

Tags: adapter, wireless, opennetcf

I am using OpenNETCF to find wireless adapters on **Motorola MC-75** device, but it do not show me any wireless adpaters. When i use “Wireless Companion” to search the wifi it does show all wifi.

I have unchecked the 802.11d and choose **Motorola JEDI WIFI** Driver. Does Motorola JEDI WIFI is WZC compatible?
But same code is working on other HTC windows device.

Please suggest.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The SDF's code base can only enumerate what the platform tells it.  Frst it asks NDIS what adapters it knows about.  For each of them, it asks WZC if it has the same one registered, if not it asks NDIS if it at least thinks it's a wireless adapter.

If the adapter driver doesn't register with WZC and doesn't report itself as wireless to NDIS, then all we can tell is that it's a NetworkInterface, so that's the instance type you get.  Some OEMs choose to have proprietary APIs to control the radio (yeah, I'm looking at you Cisco!) and the drivers use them instead of publishing a public, common interface.

Unfortunately, there's little that you can do, short of getting the API docs from the OEM (good luck with that) and updating the code base for that specific driver.